# Automapper convertion from a class with list<typeA> to class with list<typeB>

Tags: c#, automapper, automapping

```
Class SourceClass
{
    string name {get;set;}
    IList<TypeA> typeAList {get;set;}
}
Class DestinationClass
{
    string name {get;set;}
    IList<TypeB> typeBList {get;set;}
}
```

How to map this two class using automapper ?

Try 1:-
            `Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(d => d.typeBList, s => s.MapFrom(x => x.typeAList.Select(a => new typeB() { prop1 = a.prop1, prop2 = a.prop2 }).ToList<typeB>()));`

I am getting runtime conversion error for this .

Try 2:-
            `Mapper.CreateMap<typeB,typeA>().ForMember(d=>d.prop1,opt=>opt.MapFrom(s=>s.prop1));`
             `Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(d => d.typeBList, s => s.MapFrom(x => x.typeAList));`

Error :-
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
typeA -> typeB

typeA -> typeB

Destination path:
typeB.typeB0[0]

Source value:
typeA

Comment: You need to create map for `TypeA` and `TypeB` also. Aslo try once `s.MapFrom(x => x.typeAList.Select(a => new typeB() { prop1 = a.prop1, prop2 = a.prop2 })`

Comment: Could it be done using `covertusing()` method?

Answer (score 0):

you can used the following code for an auto mapper

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass ,DestinationClass>();
```

Comment: but how auto mapper will handle type mismatch between typeAList and typeBList? I am getting error.

Comment: your both classes should be same variable names, so plz change your class variable name

Comment: its not about variable name , typeALList is list of custom type TypeA and typeBList is list of custom type typeB . I want to map this both .

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the top two types and the list element types:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>();
Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>();
```

AutoMapper maps collection types automatically, but each element is mapped individually so you'll need to create maps for any element types.